# Form attribute "onsubmit" not working properly

Tags: html, forms, onsubmit

```
<form action="Verification" method="post" onsubmit='return (if (document.getElementById("1").value===document.getElementById("2").value))' >
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" required/><br>
        Email: <input type='email' name='email' id="1" required/><br>
        Confirm Email: <input type='email' name='confirm' id="2" required/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    </form>
```

I am wondering whether I can stop the form being submitted if the two emails are not the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do something like a javascript that compares the two values and if they aren't the same returns false. Give the two inputs a name or grab the values by id then do something like below onsubmit:

```
    function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["parentsEmail"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["parentsEmailConfirmation"].value;
    if (x != y) {
        alert("Let them know it's wrong here.");
        return false;
        }
    //else finish submission process
    }
```

Comment: I did - the form "onsubmit" attribute has that code

Comment: I've edited some sample code into my comment. Hopefully it steers you in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery validate
https://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/